# Is there a way to increment the value of a sql column without reading it

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I wanted to know if there is a way I can directly increment the value of a column without reading the current value.
something like:

```
update table `user` set cnt = cnt+1
```

The above statement gave me a syntax error, but I am sure there has to be something for it.

Thanks

Comment: Drop the `table` from the statement and you're there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just `UPDATE`, not `UPDATE TABLE`.

Comment: +1: Supporting link to documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html